# Validate text filed to display phone number in (999) 999-9999 format

Tags: community, validation

I want to input the mobile number in the Text field after saving the record the mobile number should display in (999) 999-9999 format.

I've tried creating a formula field of text and gave the below formula

```
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE( Phone__c ,
 '.', NULL),
 ' ', NULL), 
'-', NULL), 
')', NULL),
 '(', NULL)
```

But it doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me doing this?

Comment: Try this regex ^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$   here https://regexr.com/3c53v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex ^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s./0-9]*$

here [regexr.com/3c53v](http://regexr.com/3c53v)